# Bloom Filter about filtering in oracle

Tags: oracle, execution-plan, oracle-12c, parallelism

I read a great blog about bloom filter in Oracle, and I have a few questions about [the Bloom filter use case - Filtering](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/11514.usage-of-bloom-filter-in-oracle#bloom-filter-use-case-__002d-filtering)  in this blog.

```
    SQL> CREATE TABLE DIMENSION
      (
         col1,
         col2
      ) AS
      SELECT MOD( ROWNUM, 10 ),
             ROWNUM
      FROM   DUAL
      CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 100;

    Table created.

    SQL> CREATE TABLE FACT
      (
         col1,
         col2
      ) AS
      SELECT MOD( ROWNUM, 25 ),
             ROWNUM
      FROM   DUAL
      CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 1000000;

    Table created.

    SQL> exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(USER, 'DIMENSION');

    PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

    SQL> exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(USER, 'FACT');

    PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


    SQL> SELECT /*+ parallel(8) */ count( * )
         FROM   FACT,
                DIMENSION
         WHERE  DIMENSION.col1 = 1 AND
                DIMENSION.col2 = FACT.col2;

      COUNT(*)
    ----------
           100
```

The execution plan is as follows:

```
    SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null,null,'ALLSTATS ALL'));

    PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    SQL_ID  587ty27pjwphu, child number 0
    -------------------------------------
    SELECT /*+ parallel(8) */ count(*) FROM FACT, DIMENSION WHERE DIMENSION.col1 = 1 AND DIMENSION.col2 = FACT.col2

    Plan hash value: 4106007966
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Id  | Operation                | Name      | Starts | E-Rows |   TQ  |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib | A-Rows |
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT         |           |      1 |        |       |      |            |      1 |
    |   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE          |           |      1 |      1 |       |      |            |      1 |
    |   2 |   PX COORDINATOR         |           |      1 |        |       |      |            |      8 |
    |   3 |    PX SEND QC (RANDOM)   | :TQ10000  |      0 |      1 | Q1,00 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |      0 |
    |   4 |     SORT AGGREGATE       |           |      4 |      1 | Q1,00 | PCWP |            |      4 |
    |*  5 |      HASH JOIN           |           |      4 |    100 | Q1,00 | PCWP |            |    100 |
    |   6 |       JOIN FILTER CREATE | :BF0000   |      4 |    100 | Q1,00 | PCWP |            |    400 |
    |*  7 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL | DIMENSION |      4 |    100 | Q1,00 | PCWP |            |    400 |
    |   8 |       JOIN FILTER USE    | :BF0000   |      4 |   1000K| Q1,00 | PCWP |            |    102 |
    |   9 |        PX BLOCK ITERATOR |           |      4 |   1000K| Q1,00 | PCWC |            |    102 |
    |* 10 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL| FACT      |     71 |   1000K| Q1,00 | PCWP |            |    102 |
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
    ---------------------------------------------------
       5 - access("DIMENSION"."COL2"="FACT"."COL2")
       7 - filter("DIMENSION"."COL1"=1)
      10 - access(:Z>=:Z AND :Z<=:Z)
           filter(SYS_OP_BLOOM_FILTER(:BF0000,"FACT"."COL2"))

    Note
    -----
       - Degree of Parallelism is 8 because of hint
```

My question is as follows:

- Does the bloom filter prevents **all rows** or **some rows** from table FACT that do not join table DIMENSION from being needlessly distributed?
- Is the bloom filter created in parallel by **the set of parallel execution processes that scanned table DIMENSION** or **the set of parallel execution processes that later perform hash join**?

UPDATED

My second question is not very well, actually I want to confirm my understanding of the execution plan as follows:

1. the execution process first load DIMENSION table data (producer) and at the same time send the rows to the execution process which later perform  hash join (consumer). These consumers execution process first build bloom filter.
2. the execution process load FACT table data (producer) ant at the same time send the rows to the execution process which later perform hash join (consumer). These consumer execution process probe FACT table by bloom filter created in step 1.
3. DIMENSION table data which load in step 1 as driving table (build table), and FACT data which filter by bloom filter in step 2 as driven table (probe table) are doing hash join to return result.

So I think the creation of bloom filter happened in the execution process that later perform hash join not the execution process load DIMENSION table data.

Is my understanding correct?

My reference:

- [the Bloom filter use case - Filtering](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/11514.usage-of-bloom-filter-in-oracle#bloom-filter-use-case-__002d-filtering)
- [How Parallel Execution Works](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/parallel002.htm#i1006328)
- [Bloom Filter in Oracle](https://antognini.ch/papers/BloomFilters20080620.pdf)
- [Hash Joins](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_join.htm#GUID-91E61BDC-E5F2-49FA-99AE-DD88A2FBB4FB)

Comment: The result of the test select ( count(*) ) is 10 and not 100 and I think also the plan data (Actual Rows) do not match to this data. This error occurs already in the cited "the Bloom filter use case - Filtering". Maybe the `MOD( ROWNUM, 10 )` expression was added afterwards. Maybe it replaced a `ROWNUM` or a `MOD( ROWNUM, 100 )`, I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the bloom filter prevents **all rows** or **some rows** from table FACT that do not join table DIMENSION from being needlessly distributed?

Look at [Antognini's article](https://antognini.ch/papers/BloomFilters20080620.pdf)! A bloom filter does not prevent false positives. This means exactly  that 
a "bloom filter prevents [...] [only] some rows from table FACT that do not join table DIMENSION from being needlessly distributed". Of course there may be situation where it avoids false positive. This is the case in the example of [Joe Obbish](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/159781/2047): If one has to filter 1 value from only 25 possible values this can be done without false positives with a bloom filter.

> Is the bloom filter created in parallel by **the set of parallel execution processes that scanned table DIMENSION or the set of parallel execution processes that later perform hash join**?

To create the bloom filter one has to scan the table `DIMENSION` and add every `COL2` value to the filter. 
Look at [Antognini's plan at p.5](https://antognini.ch/papers/BloomFilters20080620.pdf):

[image]

You can see that the `PX JOIN FILTER CREATE` step is done by the Q1,02 process group. 
This is the group  that is responsible for joining the data and not the group Q1,00 that scans the table T1.

Comment: Very clear, I should have finished Antognini's article. I just skim the theory of bloom filter and do not read the case carefully. Thanks for your reminder and patience.

Answer (score 3):

A good way to observe what Oracle is actually doing with parallel processes is to use the [Real-Time SQL Monitoring](http://oracledoug.com/serendipity/index.php?/archives/1506-Real-Time-SQL-Monitoring-in-SQL-Developer.html) feature in SQL Developer. Note that this requires the target database to be licensed for the Oracle Tuning pack (the software also warns you of this).

Let's start by looking at a SQL Monitor report for your query with a NO_PARALLEL hint:

[image: DOP 1 query]

As expected Oracle gets back all 1 million rows from the FACT table. You can tell by looking at the column for the actual number of rows.

Now let's run it with a PARALLEL(4) hint:

[image: DOP 4 query]

The actual number of rows fetched from the FACT table is just 10 due to the bloom filter. This tool can show also show you how many different data flow operations there are as well as information about parallel slave sets. For this query there's just one data flow operation. You can map back parts of the query to the data flow operations by paying attention to the color of the person icon on the left of the operation column. There's also a tab with more information about the data flow operations:

[image: parallel workers]

In this example, lines 3-10 were run in parallel by a single data flow operation.

For the parallel slave sets, you can observe this by looking at the name column. Here there is just `:TQ10000` which corresponds to `Q01,00`. You can check the timeline of the query to get an idea of when Oracle performed certain operations, but Oracle completes the query too quickly for that to happen here.

Let's try another test but with 100X the data as before. I used the same table structures as in the previous example. Here is a screenshot of the finished SQL Monitor report:

[image: SQL monitor 100X]

By using the timeline you can see which operations were executed first and which were executed concurrently. You can also see a difference in the actual rows on line 10 (1135) with the actual rows on line 5 (1000). This means that the bloom filter allowed 135 false positive rows to make it to the hash join.

Going back to your original questions to answer them directly:

> Does the bloom filter prevents all rows or some rows form table FACT that do not join table DIMENSION from being needlessly distributed?

It depends on the queries and the data in the tables referenced by the queries. Sometimes the bloom filter will filter out all unnecessary rows and sometimes it will only filter out some unnecessary rows.

> Is the bloom filter created in parallel by the set of parallel execution processes that scanned table DIMENSION or the set of parallel execution processes that later perform hash join?

In this example query the same set of parallel slave processes does all of the work. For expensive enough queries you can observe the order of operations using the timeline.

Comment: Nice tool, thanks for your post which inspire me much more. For the first question, bloom filter is a  probabilistic data structure so there is a chance to have false positive result. So even for this simple case I mentioned in this question, it's possible to have some false rows left in fact data set which will be verified in next hash join operation.

Comment: I have updated my second question. Thanks for you answer!!

Comment: "For this table the bloom filter prevents all unnecessary rows from being distributed. In other more complicated queries a bloom filter may not filter out all unnecessary rows. Consider ..." I think that does not depend on the complexity of the table but on the cardinality of the column. You do not need  a large bloom filter  if you want to select exactly 1 out of 25.

Comment: @miracle173 Yeah, I slightly misunderstood what he was asking with this question. His test case isn't really designed to demonstrate the effect that he was hoping to see. I might run a few more when I get access to an Oracle database.

Comment: @JoeObbish  Yes, you are correct. The second question doesn't match my test case. And I think the test case in Antognini's article is what I want. Sorry to confuse you. Thank you for your answer.